# configure apache module on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, apache, module, ubuntu-16.04

I created an hello world module on ubuntu 16.04

```
#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_config.h>

static int helloworld_handler(request_rec* r)
{
    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "helloworld"))
        return DECLINED;

    if (r->method_number != M_GET)
        return HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;

    ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html");
    ap_rprintf(r, "Hello, world!");
    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t* pool)
{
    ap_hook_handler(helloworld_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA helloworld_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    register_hooks
};
```

compiling it with this command:

```
apxs -iac mod_helloworld.c
```

I can see the module launching it

```
apache2ctl -M
```

and

```
a2enmod
```

if I run

```
sudo a2enmod helloworld
```

I can see that this module is already enabled

I also inserted this **helloworld.conf** in the folder **mods-available**

```
<Location /helloworld>
    SetHandler helloworld_handler
</Location>
```

and the file **helloworld.load** contains

```
LoadModule helloworld_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_helloworld.so
```

How should I configure it to see the output calling in the browser for instance

**http://localhost/helloworld**

**mod_helloworld.so** is under **/usr/lib/apache2/modules**

if I `root@ubuntu:/var/log/apache2# tail -f access.log`

I am getting this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2017:03:18:14 -0700] "GET /helloworld HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking "helloworld" in the C code, but setting "helloworld_handler" w/ SetHandler.  You'd need to change to "SetHandler helloworld" to get your module to not DECLINE.

Comment: thanks, I thought that the handler function had to be set